# Dashed lines do not print correctly

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, line, printing, pdf

I have a polygon with a dashed line type; when viewed in ArcMap the line type appears correct however when I print to pdf the line type does not look correct.  This might be a pdf quality problem however I am inclined to think that this is an issue within ArcMap.

[image: Image 1][image: Image 2]

Comment: What ArcGIS version? What printer (&RAM)? Try EPS or AI format - http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/17332 might be a display/print issue.

Comment: ArcMap 10.1, cutepdfwriter

Comment: It looks like you might have rasterization.  Mapperz's link will help in that case.  If you can't turn the polygon layer off or on by itself in the pdf, it is instead part of "Image" and rasterization has taken place.

Comment: DPI does not seem to be the problem.

Comment: I will suggest you to set drawing in layout and see if it  looks correct in layout view or play around changing scale.

Comment: have you tried to export it as pdf (instead of printing) ?

Comment: I have found this problem to be cause by setting a transparency to the layer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have any transparency set or picture fill (Mapperz link). Any layers in the data frame underneath those will be rasterized. Also low quality output; I mention that because the purple line looks fuzzy in the pdf version as well.